# SQL ON UPDATE CASCADE - Composite key

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I have 2 tables

```
Table1(PKFK1, PKFK2)
Table2(PKFK1, PKFK2, PKFK3)
```

I want to do an update cascade on table2 so that every time  pkfk2 is updated in table1 is does the same in table2. I have tried the following:

```
alter table Table2
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_cascadeUP FOREIGN KEY (PKFK1) REFERENCES Table1(PKFK1) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_cascadeUP2 FOREIGN KEY (PKFK2) REFERENCES Table1 (PKFK2) ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

This gives an error. How can I do the update cascade?

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: Try one `alter table`per added fk.

Comment: And what SQL capable server do you use it's is `SQL Server (MSSQL)`, `MySQL`, `PostgreSQL` or a other one?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the complete error message you get as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question do not post additional information in comments)

Comment: This question is inaccurately titled: the example tables in the question are not using Composite Foreign Keys - and `Table1`'s columns are not a composite primary-key because `Table2` has a foreign-key that references only 1 of them (SQL requires all component columns of a composite primary-key be referenced - the only workaround is using a `UNIQUE KEY` (i.e. a Secondary Key) which the OP does not seem to be using.

Answer (score 1):

Each `ALTER TABLE` needs to be its own statement. Try this:

```
alter table Table2
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_cascadeUP FOREIGN KEY (PKFK1) REFERENCES Table1(PKFK1) ON UPDATE CASCADE

alter table Table2
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_cascadeUP2 FOREIGN KEY (PKFK2) REFERENCES Table1 (PKFK2) ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Comment: Yes it's is the most valid ANSI SQL standard answer the topicstarter seams to be using the extended ALTER MySQL SQL syntax where it's is allowed to separated statements with comma within ALTER statements.

Answer (score 0):

First, you will have to delete the foreign key, and then add the foreign key with your desired requirements. Drop the foreign key from the table and then add foreign key with "ON UPDATE CASCADE". 
It would be somewhat like:

```
ALTER TABLE Table2
DROP FOREIGN KEY [foreign key name]
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_cascadeup2 FOREIGN KEY (PKFK2) REFERENCES Table1 (PKFK2) ON UPDATE 
CASCADE;
```

The other method can be "set foreign_key_checks = 0" and after altering the foreign key, you can set it back to "1".